# Jquery chosen multiple selections trouble

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have four dropdown lists that get loaded on the first page load, they all look kinda like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedAgencies, "Agencies") <br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAgencies, Model.AllAgencies, new { @class = "chosen-select", multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 350px;" })
<button type="submit" id="btnShow" name="show">Show</button>
```

Clicking the button produces results in the same view, and the dropdown list is a filter.

Total newbie in javascript, barely made this so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#AllAgenciesSelected').is(':checked')) {
            $("#SelectedAgencies_chosen").hide();
        }
    $("#AllAgenciesSelected").click(function () {
            $("#SelectedAgencies_chosen").toggle(!this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything seems to work fine, except for the part when the user returns to this page. If multiple parameters are chosen in the dropdown list, only the last one chosen is kept as selected when the page is reloaded. I'm trying to get the selected values saved somewhere and after the page is loaded again, the selections in the dropdown list populated with the saved results:

```
    var agenciesVal;
    $("#btnShow").click(function () {
        agenciesVal = $("#SelectedAgencies").value();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
    //code from before
    if (agenciesVal!=null) {
            $('#SelectedAgencies').val = agenciesVal;
        }
    });
```

I'm really new to jquery, does trying something like this even make sense? Is there an easier, more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're doing an actual *PAGE REFRESH* then the jQuery / Javascript cache is also getting cleared out. You could try storing the data in a db or local storage? You do have some issues with your jQuery, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather the selected option(s):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var agenciesVal = [];
    $("#btnShow").click(function () {
        agenciesVal[] = $.each("#SelectedAgencies option"), function( i, v ){
            $(this).index(i).attr("selected") == true; 
        });
    });
});
```

To restore the selected options..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (agenciesVal.length != null) {
        $.each(agenciesVal, function( i, v ){
            $('#SelectedAgencies option').index(i).attr('selected', true);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Still the same results, but I think your code gives me some direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is doing a page refresh because of

```
<button type="submit">
```

Does your current code works?